# Error when setting the datasource for a gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a gridview. Its datasource is set as follows.
`dtTable` is a datable in which the values for the table will be retrieved. But when setting `dtTable` as datasource I get an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". What may be the reason for this?

```
gridview.Datasource = dtTable
gridview.Databind()
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that dtTable has the records you need. This error usually means that dtTable is null.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at where the `dtTable` variable is initialised. Is it coming back as `Nothing`? Maybe you are getting another error that is being ignored. Probably the `dtTable` is the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You won't get a null reference exception if the data table is null, you will get one if the gridview is null. That's assuming that one of these two lines are *actually* generating the exception.